# PDFKit generate pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit

I need to generate PDF from html tables, and was looking for a library that allows to take html tables with full CSS and make pdf. I'm trying to do this with PDFKit. I installed and I tested some simple examples that are explained in its documentation,it works. Documentation link:[PDFKit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)

I have some tables like this,this is table that i want to convert to pdf:

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('patient_directory.make_pdf')}}" method="POST">
    <button id="download_s" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create PDF</button>
    <table class="patient-view-table" id="table_to_pdf">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Date of birth</th>
          <th>Diagnosis</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.name }}</td>
          <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.surname }}</td>
          <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.sex }}</td>
          <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.date_of_birth }}</td>    
          <td class="property-value-col">{{ patient.diagnosis }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

In form action of table above i called this method, I created a route method:

```
mod_patient_directory.add_url_rule( '/pdf',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def make_pdf(''):       
        pdfkit.from_string(table_to_pdf, 'example.pdf')
```

My problem is that when i try to generate pdf i don't know how to pass arguments, for example, how to make know that i want to generate to pdf table with `id="table_to_pdf"`?
 Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `flask` as a framework:

Have a look at some of the example [here](https://exploreflask.com/views.html#url-converters) and [here](http://code.runnable.com/Uh4qRmSwz8cHAAAN/how-to-perform-advanced-routing-in-flask-for-python-and-routes).

You can pass the form ID in as a URL parameter.

```
@app.route('/pdf/<formid>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def make_pdf(formid):
    ...
```

Comment: yes i'm using flask, i tried that but exactly in pdf method the id of the tabled is not recognized as an id, but only as a string

Comment: Can you show the current version of `make_pdf` ? I am a bit unsure where the `patient` variable comes from.